# Anonymous access in Nextcloud

Tags: nextcloud

I use current stable version of Nextcloud (`nextcloud` docker image). I want to disable an authentication window when user enter the site. Is it possible? I found only anonymous upload feature in official doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nextcloud is build around the concept that each user has it's personal (cloud) folder where he can upload, edit and share files. Therefore you cannot access the "normal" user interface **without** a log in.

However it is possible for any user to share files/folders via a link and allow editing of them without login:

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/files/sharing.html#public-link-shares

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_files/file_sharing_configuration.html

---

But just in case you rally want to give all anonymous visitors of your Nextcloud instance the option to upload and edit files anonymously, here is a possible solution:

- Create a folder `anonymous` with your admin account
- Share it via link and allow editing
- In your admin settings, go towards `Theming`: https://your-domain.com/settings/admin/theming
- Set `Anonymous Usage` as `Name` and your shared link as `Web link`

Now if you log out and access your Nextcloud instance, you'll see a link at the very bottom called `Anonymous Usage` that you (and your clients) can follow to upload files/folders or edit existing ones. All files uploaded via that link will be stored inside the `anonymous` folder and will be owned by your admin account. So make sure to set the storage quota on that account high enough.

**Be ware that**

- by visiting your Nextcloud instance **anyone** could delete all files inside `anonymous` as he doesn't need to authenticate himself.
- the visitors are not fully anonymous, as there are probably some **log files** of Nextcloud and your Webserver with their IP addresses.

Comment: what a big answer )